# Traerse datos desde un formulario a otro desde listview cargado para filtrar

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde un formulario doy clic a un botón buscar desde ese botón abro un formulario con 2 listview del listview de la izquierda debe cargar el listview de la derecha, al dar cancelar no debe pasar nada solo salir, pero si le doy clic al botón deberia traerme lo que ahí esta para mostrarlo en el textbox y así poder realizar Implementar filtros múltiples con el lenguaje C#, osea en el cuadro de texto aparecería asi fisica,quimica, castellano

Seria algo como esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el TextBox irían los nombre para luego tomar los códigos de ahi para hacer una consulta IN con varios datos

```
string sql = @"SELECT   P.PersonID,
                        P.LastName,
                        P.FirstName,
                        P.HireDate,
                        P.EnrollmentDate
               FROM Person P
                    LEFT JOIN CourseInstructor CI 
                    ON P.PersonID = CI.PersonID
               WHERE ((@FirstName IS NULL) OR (P.FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%'))
                AND ((@LastName IS NULL) OR (P.LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%'))
                AND ((@HireDateFrom IS NULL) OR (P.HireDate >= @HireDateFrom))
                AND ((@HireDateTo IS NULL) OR (P.HireDate <= @HireDateTo))
                AND ((@EnrollmentDateFrom IS NULL) OR (P.EnrollmentDate >= @EnrollmentDateFrom))
                AND ((@EnrollmentDateTo IS NULL) OR (P.EnrollmentDate <= @EnrollmentDateTo))
                AND ((@Course IS NULL) OR (CI.CourseID IN ({0})))";

if (filter.Course != null)
{
    string courseFilter = string.Join(",", filter.Course.ConvertAll(x => x.CourseID.ToString()).ToArray());
    sql = sql.Replace("{0}", courseFilter);
}
```

O si existe una referencia a un código parecido que hago esto mismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para pasar datos entre formularios lo que puedes hacer es pasarselos mediante el constructor, ejemplo:

```
Public class FormListviews : Form {

//No se como estes almacenando tus datos, aqui yo pensare que estan almacenados en un List<>
 private List<(Tipo de dato)> Personas;

 //Modificamos el constructor para que reciba los datos de las personas por medio de un parametro
 public FormListViews(List<(tipo de dato)> Personas)){
   InitComponents();
   this.Personas = Personas;
 }

}
```

Y ya solo lo llamas de manera normal

```
FormListViews Form = new FormListViews([Le pasamos la lista de datos]).Show()
```

Comment: Botón desde el formulario padre:             List<CourseEntity> selectedCourses = txtCursos.Tag as List<CourseEntity>;
            using (frmSeleccionarCursos frmcursos = new frmSeleccionarCursos(selectedCourses))
            {
                if (frmcursos.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    txtCursos.Tag = frmcursos.CursosSeleccionados;
                    txtCursos.Text = string.Join(", ", frmcursos.CursosSeleccionados.Select(x => x.Nombre).ToArray());
                }
            }

Comment: Formulario hijo         public frmSeleccionarCursos(selectedCourses)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CursosSeleccionados = selectedCourses;
        }

        public List<CourseEntity> CursosSeleccionados
        {
            get
            {
                return lstCursosSelected.Items.Cast<CourseEntity>().ToList();
            }
        }

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.. Por favor tienes un ejemplo entre dos formularios con datos tuyos para así poder tener una referencia. Es que soy nuevo y sin una referencia visual se me hace muy difícil por favor...